# Configuring Relations - OrmLite

Tags: android, ormlite

I have this two classes,

```java
public class Banda {  

    private int BandaId;
    private String Nome;
    private Date DataDeCriacao;
    private Collection<SetList> setLists;

    public Banda(){
    }
}
```

and

```java
public class Evento {

    private int EventoId;
    private String Nome;
    private Date DataDoEvento;
    private String Local;
    private String Tipo;
    private Banda banda;

    public Evento() {
    }
}
```

I'm trying configure his database creation using OrmLite, and I have this config class:

```java
public class BandaConfiguration extends DatabaseTableConfig<Banda>{

    public BandaConfiguration() {

        ArrayList<DatabaseFieldConfig> fields = new ArrayList<>();
        fields.add(getBandaIdField());
        fields.add(getNomeField());
        fields.add(getDataDeCriacaoField());
        setFieldConfigs(fields);
    }

    private DatabaseFieldConfig getBandaIdField() {
        DatabaseFieldConfig fieldBandaId = new DatabaseFieldConfig();
        fieldBandaId.setFieldName("BandaId");
        fieldBandaId.setColumnName("BandaId");
        fieldBandaId.setGeneratedId(true);
        return fieldBandaId;
    }

    private DatabaseFieldConfig getNomeField(){
        DatabaseFieldConfig fieldNome = new DatabaseFieldConfig();
        fieldNome.setFieldName("Nome");
        fieldNome.setColumnName("Nome");
        fieldNome.setDataType(DataType.STRING);
        fieldNome.setWidth(100);
        return fieldNome;
    }

    private DatabaseFieldConfig getDataDeCriacaoField(){
        DatabaseFieldConfig fieldDataDeCriacao = new DatabaseFieldConfig();
        fieldDataDeCriacao.setFieldName("DataDeCriacao");
        fieldDataDeCriacao.setColumnName("DataDeCriacao");
        fieldDataDeCriacao.setDataType(DataType.DATE_STRING);
        fieldDataDeCriacao.setFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        return fieldDataDeCriacao;
    }
}
```

I don't want to use annotations because I want to keep my domain module with no framework, like an pure Java code layer.

So my doubt is, how can I configure the relation between this two entites?

Thanks for all!